# Small if-else issue python

Tags: python-3.x

```
   dct = {1:'James', 2:'Alex', 3:'Thomas'}
   if dct == 'James':
       print('There is a James in the dictionary.')
   else:
       print("There is no James.")
```

I can't seem to figure out why this if-else statement isn't working, I know it's something small but I keep getting the wrong output. Anyone know why? Is it a problem with my dictionary? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `{1:'James', 2:'Alex', 3:'Thomas'}` is not the same thing as `'James'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
dct = {1:'James', 2:'Alex', 3:'Thomas'}
if 'James' in dct.values():
    print('There is a James in the dictionary.')
else:
    print("There is no James.")
```

1. You need the `in` operator to compare `'James'`
2. You need to somehow iterate over the value of your dict, so getting a list with `.values()` and using `in` as I said in 1. is the easiest and most concise way.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! I just started using dictionaries so I've been trying basic functions with them, learning all the uses of dictionaries is still a work in progress.

Comment: Don't worry we have all been there! keep it up, we all need to improve. glad I could help! Just to be sure though, do you understand the mechanic behind my answer? Don't hesitate if you have any question.

Comment: @BlakeMcLaughlin Keep in mind that if you're going to be doing `in` checks on the _values_, those values should be keys instead, or else you defeat the purpose of dictionaries, which are efficient constant time lookups.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If I understand correctly, I totally agree with you. He could use a list if he does not need dictionary structure. But if not this is how I would implement it.